# Hide elements until the page finishes loading - using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, loading

I've just write a dead-simple code to hide all the elements until the page finishes loading and display an indicator while loading.. (**It works**).

so what I'm asking for is to know if I'm doing it right and what are you going to suggest.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="loading">
        <img src="indicator.gif"/>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <!-- page content goes here --> 
    </div>
</body>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hide();
     });

    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".content").fadeIn("slow");
     });
```

Answer (score 14):

You probably want to hide the content div from the start to avoid any possible page flicker depending on what's being loaded on the page.

```
<body>
  <div class="loading">
    <img src="indicator.gif"/>
  </div>

  <div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <!-- page content goes here --> 
  </div>
</body>


$(window).load(function(){
  $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
  $(".content").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

A slight improvement on this Javascript is to use a callback on the fadeout so the fade in starts when the fadeout has completed. This gives you a much smoother transition.

```
<body>
  <div class="loading">
    <img src="indicator.gif"/>
  </div>

  <div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <!-- page content goes here --> 
  </div>
</body>


$(window).load(function(){
  $(".loading").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(".content").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```